# My Scrapy spider can't extract data from the next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

so I am asked to scrape all the job details from a website, however my spider succeeds to get the link to the next page but only extracts the the data from the first one
This is my spider:

```
name = 'jobs'
allowed_domains = ['www.tanitjobs.com/jobs']
start_urls = ['https://www.tanitjobs.com/jobs']

def parse(self, response):
    pass

    all_jobs = response.css(".listing-item__jobs")

    for job in all_jobs:
        item = {
            'jobname' : job.css("article.listing-item div.listing-item__title a::text").getall(),
            "companyname" : job.css(".listing-item__info--item-company::text").extract(),
            "city" : job.css(".listing-item__info--item-location::text").extract() ,
            }

        yield item

    next_page = response.css(".pad_right_small a ::attr(href)").extract_first()
    if next_page:
       next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
       yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

[This is the result that i got after running the spider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUeJ9.png)

if anyone knows what seems to be the problem, i really need your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the space between a and ::attr(href) is wrong and also you might need to make the link absolute.

Comment: @pguardiario it is absolute i just used the urljoin to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

> `allowed_domains = ['www.tanitjobs.com/jobs']`

as is a dead giveaway by its variable name, one should only put allowed **domains** in that list, and what you have is a *partial* URL in there, which causes the offsite filter to reject the request

Unless you have a specific need otherwise, I would suggest only listing the base **domain** in that value:

```
allowed_domains = ['tanitjobs.com']
```